# How to add options which appears on swipe gesture in List View in Windows 10

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am new to Windows 10 and I just came across Windows 10 new Outlook App which has swipe features but my requirement of swipe is different. I want to add 3-3 options on left and right side of ListView. I also came across below Nuget package from Github but it doesn't help much

[SwipeListView](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView)

What I want to achieve is below

[image]

Please can someone suggest a good and easy way to add swipe actions in ListView.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no library ready made for your need.

You can achieve the effect using custom ListViewItem. You will need a trick along the way to get the ListView accept TranslateX manipulation: Set ManipulationMode of the ItemsPresenter inside ListView template to `TranslateX, System`.

The rest is quite easy: you set manipulation mode of the custom ListViewItem to `TranslateX, System`, and handle ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta and ManipulationCompleted events. You also need to put UI underlay of the custom ListViewItem.

I can not give complete code sample given the big scope of your question. But you can take a loot at [Comet](https://github.com/nmetulev/comet) to get the basic ideal of how to handle things.

Answer (score 0):

There's no library that does exactly this, as far as I know. There are a few things that get close, however, and you could probably modify them for your needs. I'd recommend taking a look at [this one](https://github.com/GSonofNun/FedoraControls). All you should need to do is slightly modify the template control, then set the control as the content of the `ListViewItem`.

However, it should be noted that having to tap the command pretty much defeats the purpose of being able to swipe the item; it would actually be faster for the user if you just used a button on the item which launches a `CommandPopup`. (Unless, of course, you do something really interesting and completely impractical and would launch whichever command they *stop swiping* on.)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I got a Nuget Package which meets my requirements

[LLMListView](https://github.com/brookshi/LLMListView)

It has some very useful options as the following

- Swipe Left/Right with one action
- Swipe Left/Right with one action with animation
- Swipe Right with fixed and multiple actions

Some extras

1. Pull to refresh
2. Pull with a button
3. Load More
4. Load More in Group view

Here is the screenshot
[LLMListView Demo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brookshi/LLMListView/master/list%20view.gif)